# Finding 'minimal' linear span

Tags: linear-algebra

Need help please for an efficient solution for the following problem (example):
Given `m` (32) numbers, not necessarily unique.
Which sum up to `k` (1024).
You need to find `n` (8) numbers from which you can compose all the `m` numbers in such a way that the **total instances of the `n` numbers are minimal**.
An error `e` (10%) is allowed.

For example:
`m1 = 3, m2 = 12, m3 = 60, m4 = 80, m5 = 90`
can have this solution:
`n1 = 3, n2 = 4, n3 = 20`
which yields:

```
m1 = 1*n1 = 1*3
m2 = 3*n2 = 3*4 = 12
m3 = 3*n3 = 3*20 = 60
m4 = 4*n3 = 4*20 = 80
m5 = 4*n3 + 1*n2 + 2*n1 = 4*20 + 2*4 + 1*3 = 91
```

total `n` numbers used to build all the `m` numbers is 18.

Comment: Why not use $4n_3+n_2+2n_1=90$, with an error of zero?

Comment: you're right, corrected, anyway, the point was just showing an example of the problem. still what I'm looking for a generic approach to solve this linear span problem.